# How to structure schemas better in Synapse SQL dedicated pool

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Using Azure Synapse , Dedicated SQL pool.

How can I structure my tables underneath a button that represents the schema?

This is a small issue that really makes a big impact when many tables and schemas will be used in the database, and users will need to navigate to the correct schema quickly.

I tried dragging the schema under over the tables section, but nothing worked.

Comment: Could you please provide the procedure what you have tried and what you got in image format for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

to structure the table first we need to create schema in sql dedicated pool using below command

```
CREATE SCHEMA <schemaName>
```

we need to create table using above created schema with required columns with suitable data types to that column.
Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE <tableName>(col1 dataType,col2 dataType)
```

I created external table in dedicated sql pool in synapse following below steps:

Schema creation:

[image]

Created external data source:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  DATA SOURCE [DATASOURCE] WITH
(
      LOCATION = '<location>',

)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

created external file format:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  FILE FORMAT [FileFormat1] WITH
(
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT
)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I created external table using above data source and file format using below code:

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL  TABLE [wwi].[information2]
(
[Id] INT
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION = '<folder/file>',

    DATA_SOURCE = [DATASOURCE1],

    FILE_FORMAT = [FileFormat1]
)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

In this we can structure the table in synapse dedicated pool.